# Powershell Script - Find the a list with path of the password protected .xlsx AND .xls files in a network folder

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am currently working on finding a way to get a list with path of all the .xlsx and .xls file that are password protected in a network drive that contains tons and tons of folders and sub folders. I put together this script below that works fine, but it only returns **.xlsx** files, none of the **.xls** files with password protected were returned. I am wondering if anyone knows how to get the .xls file with password or any other script that would get this job done? Appreciate all your help!

Script

```
$path = "C:\Users\DC\Desktop"
$dest = "C:\Users\DC\Desktop\ExcelWithPassword.txt"
$Full = Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xlsx*, *.xls* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$List = select-string -pattern "<encryption" $Full 
foreach ($file in $List) {
    $file.path | Out-File $dest -Append -Force
}
```

The output is basically a list of paths where those password protected files are located.

Answer (score 0):

unless you have other files in the target directory tree, with an '*.xl* extension. Why are you doing this ...

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xlsx*, *.xls* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

... you only need this...

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xl* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

If you are after just the full path, ask for it, using this ...

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xl* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select-Object -Property Fullname

# Results
<#
FullName                                  
--------                                  
D:\Temp\NewFolder\Test.xlsx               
D:\Temp\Test.xls                          
D:\Temp\Test.xlsx                            
#>
```

... or this.

```
(Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xl* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName

# Results
<#
D:\Temp\NewFolder\Test.xlsx
D:\Temp\Test.xls
D:\Temp\Test.xlsx
#>
```

As far as the loop, you can also shorten your code to something similar.

```
(Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xl* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select-Object -Property Fullname) -match '<encryption' | 
Out-File $dest -Append -Force
```

Or

```
(Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.xl* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName -match '<encryption' | 
Out-File $dest -Append -Force
```

You are not saying how the files were encrypted. Excel allows for protecting the sheet, the workbook, etc. You can't check a password-protected file by searching for a string without opening the file. To open the file you must use the application interface to open the file. For Excel it's:

```
### Automate Excel 

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook1 = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

$Sheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.Item(1)
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Hello from Powershell "
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Using VBA from Excel Button object"
```

Based on what you are after, there are a few other considerations you must have. Scanning and doing this across the whole network and thousands of files requires planning, and parallel processing.